# python - Can't install gensim in Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pycharm, gensim

When I use PyCharm to install gensim package, the installment failed.
The error messages were listed below:

[image]

```
Collecting gensim
  Using cached gensim-0.12.4-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy>=0.7.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gensim)
Collecting smart-open>=1.2.1 (from gensim)
  Using cached smart_open-1.3.2-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from gensim)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gensim)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): boto>=2.32 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): bz2file in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
Collecting requests==2.8.1 (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
  Using cached requests-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting httpretty==0.8.10 (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
  Using cached httpretty-0.8.10-py2-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: requests, httpretty, smart-open, gensim
  Found existing installation: requests 2.7.0
    Uninstalling requests-2.7.0:

You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 726, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 314, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.7.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
```

---

And I also use pip to install, but also failed....
The error messages were listed below:

```
chenguanyingdeMacBook-Pro:~ ChenGuanYing$ sudo pip install gensim
Password:
The directory '/Users/ChenGuanYing/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The directory '/Users/ChenGuanYing/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting gensim
  Downloading gensim-0.12.4-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (2.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.5MB 178kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy>=0.7.0 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from gensim)
Collecting smart-open>=1.2.1 (from gensim)
  Downloading smart_open-1.3.2-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.5.0 (from gensim)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.3 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from gensim)
Collecting boto>=2.32 (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
  Downloading boto-2.39.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 312kB/s 
Collecting bz2file (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
  Downloading bz2file-0.98.tar.gz
Collecting requests==2.8.1 (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
  Downloading requests-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (497kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 499kB 948kB/s 
Collecting httpretty==0.8.10 (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
  Downloading httpretty-0.8.10-py2-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: boto, bz2file, requests, httpretty, smart-open, six, gensim
  Running setup.py install for bz2file
  Found existing installation: requests 2.7.0
    Uninstalling requests-2.7.0:
      Successfully uninstalled requests-2.7.0
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 726, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 314, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-vV05uu-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

---

Thank for your help, and sorry for that my English is very pool.

Answer (score 2):

To give yourself permissions to change the contents of that folder, you can execute the following:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /library/Python/2.7
```

This worked for me when encountering an errno:13

Answer (score 0):

First, I install NumPy and SciPy.
Then I install gensim successfully!

Answer (score 0):

Gensim needs Python, SciPy and Numpy with their appropriate versions.
You can find theim here : https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/install.html
I advise you to install them with Anaconda.